# Capturing more detailed errors in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ftp

**How do I retrieve a more detailed error message?**

I ran an individual task to upload a file:

[image]

And the response I got was:

[image]

**Where do I go to get more details on what actually failed?**

Please note that I am able to login and perform this operation manually through an FTP client like filezilla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using EventHandlers for OnError events and logging to a table?

<s>http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2005/06/11/SSIS_3A00_-Custom-Logging-Using-Event-Handlers.aspx</s>

EMC (the company that hired the blogger who wrote the original blog post) took down his migrated content. So here is the above post on waybackmachine -- [SSIS: Custom Logging Using Event Handlers](https://web.archive.org/web/20090903140500/http://blogs.conchango.com/jamiethomson/archive/2005/06/11/1593.aspx)

I've used this exact method on a few SSIS packages, and it's pretty easy to setup.  The OnPostExecute is really excessive, but great for demonstration purposes.

NB:  I'm not sure it will give you detailed FTP error codes if it's not showing them in debug mode.

For FTP troubleshooting -- if you're using any variable/dynamic connection parameters that are changed at run time, you might want to pop them up in a message box, or save them to a file as they are set so you can review them later.